# How do I uninstall Drupal from Amazon EC2 Micro Instance?

Tags: drupal, amazon-ec2, uninstallation

I accidentally uploaded Drupal 7 onto the Amazon EC2 user and I would like to know if there is away I can uninstall Drupal 7 so that I may add Drupal 6.30.

Comment: Yes, what command do I use in order to delete these files?

Comment: `rm -rf /the/path/to/your/drupal/install`. If you're going to run a server you really need to learn some basic command line usage.

Comment: I am trying to :) I have kind of been thrown into this without training, so I am learning as I go. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the sites folder from your linux machine from the path: /var/www/html.
Also, if you are looking to install any other CMS instead of drupal you can unzip it directly in the folder mentioned above. Here is a link to a good tutorial by Amazon folks on installing Wordpress: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/hosting-wordpress.html